# EV3 Programme won't load to brick

Tags: ev3, programming

I have installed EV3 on my PC and am trying to load a program into an NXT 1 Brick.
When I click the down load button on the EV3 screen the Brick beeps twice and the program does not load.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check if there aren't any logic problems like for example putting a motor in a infinite loop with no end?

Answer (score 1):

EV3 software can be used with the NXT brick. It may require a firmware update. I think firmware 1.31 is the minimum.